# Should I use OAuth 2 for first party application?

Tags: oauth-2.0

It seems OAuth 2 was designed for 3rd party application instead of 1st party application.

I know OAuth 2 is a delegation protocol, resource owner grants permission to client to use resource server.

If I build and REST API for my mobile app how can I handle login flow? Do I have to use OAuth 2 or just use a custom method instead?

Answer (score 1):

OAuth is about more than third party access and is a much more architectural topic. I would summarize it in terms of application capabilities:

- Multiple ways for users to authenticate - for best Login UX with familiar credentials and strong security
- Best options for managing and protecting data by area, with many design patterns around claims and runtime behaviour
- Best options for integrating with business partners and meeting some types of regulation
- Enabing simple code by externalizing a lot of the difficult stuff from your apps

Pretty much everyone is standardized on using OAuth based solutions these days, and there is no real mainstream alternative for mobile apps and APIs.

It is a journey though and in the early days it is about choosing your moments and getting buy in from your stakeholders. As a first base I would maybe aim for these 2 qualities:

- Decide on a free or low cost (cloud?) Authorization Server - and see if your stakeholders are happy with the Login UX and user onboarding aspects
- Implement a mobile proof of concept app that uses OAuth. If there are no blocking issues you will then have better caabilities than previously.

If it helps, see these 2 blog posts of mine, which aim to provide a fast mobile OAuth setup with the most standard libraries and their official samples:

- [iOS Mobile Sample](https://authguidance.com/2018/02/20/ios-setup)
- [Android Mobile Sample](https://authguidance.com/2018/02/20/android-setup)

Comment: Can I skip consent form if I use OAuth 2 Authorization Code Flow for 1st-party app?
I own both app and API, so users will have full permission. They don't need to grant permission for each API.

Comment: Yes - consent is used when personal assets are involved - eg the user's Google Docs - if the assets are specific to an app or software company it is common to skip it. This is not always explained well.