# Limitations of SAML as compared to OAuth

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, openid-connect, saml, saml-2.0

I know how SAML works and I know how OAuth and OPENIDConnect works. I know that SAML is for authentication and OAuth for authorization. but in certain articles it is mentioned that when in 2007 iPhone came in SAML lacked authentication in that case ( for mobile apps ), I am unable to understand that besides delegated authorization, why we needed OAuth to tackle mobile authentication problem  ( now being done by OPENIDConnect ) Or how SAML was unable to deal with that issue. can someone help resolve this confusion. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAML was not designed for allowing the application to authenticate. It depends on a pre-shared key mechanism for signing/validation, encryption/decryption that is better handled at a server with the attributes being fed to the downstream app in some other manner (like OAuth or OIDC). Can you imagine needing to update a couple million app installs just because the IdP wants to rotate their certificate? Or, worse yet, the IdP's private key gets compromised? Key management in SAML is a difficult enough process, and if you fail, there's a name for the attack you are exposed to - the Golden SAML Attack.

OAuth and OIDC, on the other hand, were designed in such a way thatthe private keys for signing and encryption are expected to rotate regularly. The public keys for decryption and validation are shared on an accessible endpoint by the Authorization Server (AS) or OIDC Provider (OP), which is publicly announced by the AS/OP in the required metadata endpoint. This makes it so that the downstream application that is using the AS/OP can get the keys it needs when they rotate. Generally, the application will cache the keys and use them until failure, at which point it goes and retrieves the new set.

Answer (score 2):

A few days ago I did this exercise to identify the applications of SAML and OAUTH. I will paste my findings here.

**About - SAML** 

•   Authentication
•   Authorization (based on claim rules and assertion attributes)
•   Mainly designed for the browser based login flow
•   Best fit for enterprise applications which rely on centralized user repository
•   On-Premise and Cloud application federations are easy (e.g. sync user repository with the cloud replica), user attributes can be passed easily in this case
•   Attributes can contain the information(credentials) to connect to another third party application (not recommended)
•   Supports encrypted assertion for better security
•   Single Req-Res contains the Assertion, avoiding any additional calls to the IdP
•   Centralized management of user and authorization data
•   Federation metadata involves complex structure, attribute definitions, public certificates, signing algorithms, etc.
•   Periodic certificate rollover, CRL management, Claim rules management

**About - OAuth**

•   Authorization
•   Requires separate authentication provider (usually coupled with authorization server)
•   Best fit for multi-domain, multi user repository scenarios
•   Useful in controlling access over individual resources such as account details, file or a service. Temporary/Permanent access can be granted.
•   Simple to understand, easy to integrate. Reduces lot of extra work client has to perform
•   **Resource owner controls the access on resources, can selectively grant access to various functionalities for other applications**
•   Decoupling of Authentication from the business logic
•   Different GRANT TYPE support for different use cases
•   Once the token is acquired, SP must make additional API calls to fetch necessary information/resource
•   Weak standardization – Every IdP can customize the implementation, which invites customizations at SP side
•   Rely solely on HTTPS for encryption, no additional encryption defined for the data being transferred

To Answer your question - **Where you will find it difficult to apply SAML**

•   Inter-application communications
•   Backend jobs, Schedulers, business logic where user interaction is not involved
•   Communicating with external IDPs which are not managed or controlled by your organization

Answer (score 1):

OAuth and OpenID Connect are JSON based and work well in any technology, including web and mobile.

SAML is an older (back end) standard based on XML. It is still widely used in Identity providers, for signing users in.

These days people write apps (UIs and APIs) in terms of OAuth and OpenID Connect - and never use SAML directly. This results in simpler code in mobile apps, single page apps and APIs.

This means the apps interact with an Authorization Server (AS). The AS can talk to identity providers (to support multiple ways to sign users in). This can include integration with SAML providers if required.

See also my [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67572611/should-i-use-oauth-2-for-first-party-application/67575257#67575257) on thinking of OAuth in terms of application capabilities.

Comment: this is not answering my question of limitations that we had in saml like mobile app authentication in particular ( so we needed oauth )

Comment: Technically a mobile app could build a SAML authorization request and receive a SAML authorization response. This would then involve verifying signatures contained in the doc using X509. It may also need to use secrets if the SAML assertion used an encrypted payload  At some point this would require the help of an API, since SAML was designed only for back end clients. One key difference with OAuth is that flows are designed to also be used by public clients, and with more convenient JSON Web technologies.

Comment: Actually SAML is a technology to provide cookie less Single Sign On for the Web. OAuth2 is about delegated authorization. So if at all you may compare OIDC with SAML but in detail they differ a lot. E.g. SAML offers and IdP-Proxy, OIDC offers dynamic client registration.
SAML offers single logout. OIDC session manangement is still in draft (I think for years now)

Comment: Good points from Bernhard, though my answers tend to be about what is practical for most companies. Some great innovation originated from the people who built SAML and these ideas are carried forward into bodies such as the [FAPI Working Group](https://openid.net/wg/fapi/). My main point was that these days you would not build a solution for Web / Mobile UIs and APIs based on SAML, since it would not provide the best capabilities. OAuth is about more than delegation - see the [Curity Financial Grade Articles](https://curity.io/resources/financial-grade/) for some real world examples.

Comment: Just to add that SAML doesn't really support using the token to call a REST API.